# Ubuntu - Uninstall preinstalled software

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu derived Distro and I don't need most of the preinstalled programs.
Not everything is listed within the Software Center, for example a Photo-Viewer and a Music Player.

I deinstalled some software the naive way by

```
ps -u user > before
```

I opened the program to uninstall and then

```
ps -u user > after
```

and compared both lists via

```
diff before after
```

and uninstalled the programs listed.

Is there a more elegant way to list installed software?
Doing this with every program is exhausting...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
dpkg -S programname`
```

will generally tell you the name of the binary package containing `programname`. Or even

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/programname
```

Then just do

```
apt-get remove pkgname
```

or

```
apt-get purge pkgname
```

If you don't know the name of the program because you are executing it from some menu, then you would probably need to check the output of `ps` or similar.

Note: `dlocate` is a fast alternative to `dpkg -S`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Synaptic Package Manager (GUI). You can save profiles after removing the software and reapply everytime you reinstall the OS. Quite handy.